# How to return a key for the whole model in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Imagine, you have this model

```
public Class SomeModel 
{
    public string someString1 { get; set; }
    public string someString2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you want to validate this model. In FluentValidation you write this.RuleFor(m => m.{property} for each property on the model/class and when a validation error occurs, you get the key of the property that failed validation and a message.

Now, what i am wondering about, is how you can set a key for the whole model when it returns an error from validation, which validates two or more properties. (e.g. this.RuleFor(m => m).TestIfPropsAreEqual(); ) What is the correct way to approach this problem? I don't really want to write the method on a property, because that wouldn't be correct, because you are validating the whole model not a specific property.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that when validating the whole model, the returned key is empty.

Comment: You can use resharper extension. It generates equals method easily

Comment: @SerhatOz Sadly i don't have access to ReSharper. Also i have no idea what that method is.

Answer (score 0):

https://fluentvalidation.net/start#overriding-the-property-name is the answer. I can give the a name to class or new name to a property.